# React Native, unable to clean gradlew

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to clean my android gradlew file by `cd android` and `./gradlew clean` but it's showing that error, can anyone tell me how to clean it without getting that error?? please help

```
Task :react-native-localization:clean FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-localization:clean'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file 'C:\Users\DAWOR\Go-polo-master\node_modules\react-native-localization\android\build'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

no need for ./ if your in the android directory unless your using linux as for the error this just means it could not delete the specified folder could be due to permissions or a file in the folder still being in use by something

i would suggest deleting the folder your self then rerunning the command this can happen if you still have metro or the emulator open if a file is still in use by something